# Return sum of Positive Number

Tags: java, loops, recursion

I'm having to write a program in which method returns the sum of the positive numbers read , and will read the input from the user until zero is entered.

What I have so far is not calculating the sum of the positive numbers entered and I need some help please.

Here is what I have so far:

`readAndSumPositives()` *(notice you're given the Scanner, do not use System.in)* - 
reads from user until given 0 and returns sum of the positive numbers read.

Examples:

♦ user enters: 0   => return 0

♦ user enters 1 2 3 0 => returns 6 (1+2+3)

♦ user enters 1 -2 3 0 => returns 6 (1+3, skip -2 since it is negative)

```
public static int readAndSumPositives(Scanner in,PrintStream out)
{
    int input;
    int count;
    int sum;
    int total;

    sum = 0;
    count =0;
    total = sum+count;

        out.println("Please enter a number");
        input=in.nextInt();
     while(input != 0 && input != -2 && input != -3 && input != -4) {
        sum += input;
        count++;
        out.println("Enter your next positive number");
        input=in.nextInt();
    } 

    if (input == 0) {
        return sum;
    } else return input;
}
```

Here is the code that is executing when I run this method in GitBash

```
private static int readAndSumPositivesFrom(String input) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream out_bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintStream out=new PrintStream(out_bs);

    Scanner in_s = new Scanner(new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes()));
    int ans = Assignment5.readAndSumPositives(in_s,out);
    in_s.close();
    return ans;
}

@Grade(points = 20)
@Test
public void testReadAndSumPositives() {     
    Assert.assertEquals(30, readAndSumPositivesFrom("10 20 0 "));
    Assert.assertEquals(20, readAndSumPositivesFrom("10 -20 10 0 "));
    Assert.assertEquals(10, readAndSumPositivesFrom("1 2 -2 3 -3 4 -4 0 "));
}
```

Any help is appreciated and points will be awarded!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *What I have so far is not executing... Here is the code that is executing...* This question is a bit confusing.

Comment: What I mean is that it is not calculating the sum of the positive numbers entered.

Comment: What's your input? What's the output? What's the expected output?

Comment: The input is this:

Assert.assertEquals(30, readAndSumPositivesFrom("10 20 0 "));
    Assert.assertEquals(20, readAndSumPositivesFrom("10 -20 10 0 "));
    Assert.assertEquals(10, readAndSumPositivesFrom("1 2 -2 3 -3 4 -4 0 "));

Comment: Ok, and the output? Why do I have to pull teeth to get you to explain your own question?

Comment: The expected output is for the method to sum up the positive numbers that I'm passing in the AssertEquals code. It also is suppose to skip any negative numbers. Thanks

Comment: And the actual output???

Comment: I could have worded it better I know. I'm trying my best. My Java is beyond rusty

Comment: This is not a Java problem. This is about [asking a proper question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It is suppose to give me 20 points when I run the method and the values pass through, but it is not doing that.

Comment: @rls1982 Is this a codechef exercise?

Comment: No it is an exercise for school

Comment: For the last time: ***What is it doing?***

Comment: My code is not doing anything. When I run it in GitBash it is not giving me any points at all and it is suppose to give me 20 points when all of the numbers pass through. It is not summing up the numbers and it is not giving me the 20 points that I need even though it is compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning wrong values. You should return `input` when the first input is `0` and `sum` when it is not. You are doing just the opposite. Also, taking the first input outside the loop and then checking it in the loop and taking the next input in the loop is bound to cause a **logical error** if the user enters a positive number in the first place (or rather a **syntax error** since `input` is not initialized outside the loop). Do everything inside the loop and check what you are returning.

```
while(true){  //infinite loop
    out.println("Enter positive number to add, 0 to stop.");
    input = in.nextInt();
    if(input == 0)
        break;
    if(input > 0)
        sum+= input;
}
return sum;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while(input != 0 && input != -2 && input != -3 && input != -4) 
//instead of above logic,use logic mentioned below....

int sum=0;
while(input!=0)
{
    if(input>0)
     sum+=input;
     out.println("Enter your next positive number");
     input=in.nextInt();
    //What is the purpose of  using "count"?
}
return sum;
```

Comment: The purpose of `count` is simply to count the number of integers added to `sum`, though the **_value of `count` is never used_**.